# Solspace FreeForm and special characters

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have an issue with Norwegian characters in FreeForm.

In both my received mail and receipt mail the characters å æ ø don't translate, they are just jumbled.

Ive tried everything but nothing helps.

Paul